# Adding Non-Standard Attribute to asp:LinkButton inside Repeater prevents the run of OnItemCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, zurb-foundation

I am integrating a [Foundation 5 Reveal Modal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) component with an `<asp:LinkButton>`.  For the reveal modal to work it requires the addition of a non-standard HTML attribute `data-reveal-id` to the `<asp:LinkButton>`. If I do 'not' add this attribute in the `.aspx` below, then clicking the LinkButton will trigger `rptNotice_ItemCommand`. However, when `data-reveal-id` is added to the LinkButton as shown below `rptNotice_ItemCommand` does not run, and `lbMessage` is not updated. The `lbMessage` is required by the database upon submission of the modal form.

How do I get this to work?

Is there another way to keep track of the message ID?

In the `.aspx` file

```
<!-- Foundation 5 Reveal Modal -->
<div id="replyModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
    <h2>Reply to Notice</h2>
    <asp:Label ID="lbMessage" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID='tbFollowQuestion' runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%" /><br />               
    <asp:Button ID="btnFollowCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="followQuestionCancel_Clicked" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnFollowQuestion" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="followQuestionSave_Clicked" />

    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

<asp:Repeater ID="rptNotice" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptNotice_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row padding-bottom-10 border-bottom-1 margin-bottom-10">                
            <!-- LinkButton -->
            <div class="small-6 medium-2 xlarge-1 columns">
                    <asp:LinkButton data-reveal-id="replyModal" CommandName="Contact" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("MessageId")%>' ToolTip="Reply" runat="server"><img src="/images/icon/envelop.jpg" alt="Contact Us"><strong class="font-size-14">Reply</strong></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In the `.aspx.cs` file

```
public void rptNotice_ItemCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    lbMessage.Text = "MessageId: " + e.CommandArgument.ToObjectString();
}
```

Comment: a link button has an attributes property that is a collection...I think you need to add your data attribute to the attributes collection in your code behind. Something like myLinkButton.Attributes.add(myCustomAttribute)

Comment: I've tried that as well, but once I call `Attributes.add()` `rptNotice_ItemCommand()` will not trigger.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be possible parsing issue due to unknown parameter. I would suggest using CommandArgument field. Try "replyModal" to CommandArgument .

Split the value at backend and get operation type.

Comment: The Foundation 5 reveal modal needs `data-reveal-id="replyModal"` to be set otherwise the modal will not appear.  Adding it as a `CommandArgument` will prevent the click from being detected by the reveal modal Javascript.

Comment: what about setting class name which can be used by foundation 5 modal. Is that a possibility?

Comment: my understanding is that that would require re-writing the foundation 5 javascript for the reveal modal. I believe there is a good reason why they didn't use the class attribute.